# Use USB connector for charging battery and also for outputting battery voltage

Tags: batteries, usb, charging

I want to use a USB connector for charging battery and also for outputting battery voltage, depending on what is connected.
I am also thinking of two micro USB connectors. One for charging. The other for a load, like an simple LED module.

This is what I thought of:

[image]

I do not know what happens if I loop the battery voltage back to the input of the charging IC...

Is something like this possible?
Are there any alternatives?

Comment: It would not be a great idea to output battery voltage out from the same connector, not even via diode. If you accidentally plug that into something that can't handle it, like a laptop or desktop computer, it can damage the motherboard. Use a custom connector for custom loads.

Comment: I saw some chinese module which are capable of charging and even apply a load onto it. How can they do it?

Comment: They have one input for battery charger and one output from boost converter? USB is 5V so a battery would not be directly connected to the USB connector for output.

Comment: Be carefull ... Some can do the two things ! Charging and boost converter ! There is two USB port (one mini, one micro) tied together ...

Answer (score 3):

Unless you intend to support USB-C bidirectional power delivery (and all the complexity it entails), do *not* use USB this way. Have separate charge and output ports.

This is why USB power banks that aren't USB-C use the following:

- USB-micro-B for charge in
- USB-A or micro-A for power out

Prior to USB3.1, USB supported a 'dual role' mode with the OTG specification; such a device would have a 'micro-AB' connector on it. This has been superceded in USB3.1 by the USB-C method.

More here: https://blogs.synopsys.com/tousbornottousb/2018/05/03/usb-dual-role-replaces-usb-on-the-go/

Comment: The ones that do do not tend to have isolated 5V rails and can often be used as a pass through. The use of a usb a and usb b mini/micro is more due to not needing special cables. The same cable can be used to charge the bank and the phone etc.

Comment: Disagree. The device that has micro-B fpr charge and A for output will have a power-path control that prevents back-powering the USB-B side, but can support charge-and-run too if can request enough current from the host. It's not a straight pass-through.

Comment: Plenty of teardown of cheap power banks online. You can see yourself.